# how to get all set-cookie from response using nodejs

Tags: node.js, cookies, request

The server response 3 'set-cookie' info, but I can just get 2 'set-cookie', I don't know why.

http package headers:

```
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=...
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=...
Set-Cookie: Vote.PublicAccount.2779842=...
```

I get cookies using response.headers['set-cookie']
result is:

```
[ '__cfduid=...',  'ASP.NET_SessionId=...' ]
```

All my code:

```
request({
        url: '....',
        method: 'GET'
    }, function(error, response, data){
         if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(response.headers['set-cookie']);
         }
       });
```

Comment: Also having this issues. @Wilson.Guan did you ever fix this?